# Can't access vgaswitcheroo file, access denied?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, vgaswitcheroo

Hi I'm trying to change my integrated graphics card to my discrete graphics card (Nvidia GeForce 540m) and when I use the vgaswitcheroo method, I can't access the file doing this:

```
$ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
ls: cannot access /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: Permission denied
```

This is the link to the guide on using vgaswitcheroo I'm using: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

I'll be using Nvidia Unix Drivers because I'll be playing with the graphics card.

Any help? Thanks.

Ps. I'm new at Ubuntu, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is late but I just stumbled across this problem, and thought posting the solution up for future readers is the best thing to do.

The above answer by Ugo is correct but you literally need to be root, not some user with root privileges.

So the simple answer is type:

```
sudo su
```

and you should see the terminal switch from displaying `user_name@machine_name` to `root@machine_name`.

Now all vgaswitcheroo related edits should work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be root to do this. To become root, simply start the line with `sudo`:

```
sudo ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

And enter your account password when asked.

Comment: It worked but then when using `echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` it says permission denied again. I tried puting `sudo` at the beginning of that but didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to run more than one commands using sudo, just do `sudo -s` then press `enter` and enter your password. You now have root permissions and can run your commands. (when doing `sudo echo ON > /...` the elevated permissions only apply to the echo not the `>` operator)

Comment: I'm able to do `ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` with the `sudo -s` and I can do the rest but doesn't really change anything at all, I click enter and they do nothing, just opens a new empty line to write, nothing changes... Any ideas on why? Is it possible that I have all the files up to `/debug` but then vgaswitcheroo simply doesn't exist or something? Thanks!

Comment: You should probably open a new thread with this question: the first question (permission problem) seems to be fixed now. I don't know the answer of your last question, so you may have more luck in starting a new specific thread. Cheers,